# check several heights and hide an item of tall item container parent

Tags: jquery, html, css

There is a `.blog` DIV which contains three `article` each one has a `h1` and `h4`, when the `h1` meets the `.blog`'s width, it breaks into two line, so will have a taller height (taller than 50px)

```
<div class="blog">
    <article>
        <h1>Hello There</h1>
        <h4>Description 1</h4>
    </article>
    <article>
        <h1>Hello There</h1>
        <h4>Description 2</h4>
    </article>
    <article>
        <h1>Hello There I'm a long text who have a more than 50px height</h1>
        <h4>Description 3</h4>
    </article>
</div>
```

I want to hide its `h4` when it have a height taller than 50px.

```
var max=50;
$('.blog article').find('h2').each( function (){
    if($(this).height()>max)
    $("article h4").hide();
});
```

Yes I know it will hide all of the three `h4`s, so what I should do to only hide the tall `h1` container article `h4`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var max=50;
$('.blog article').find('h1').each( function (){
    if($(this).height()>max)
    $(this).next('h4').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed the `find('h2')` because it didn't appear anywhere else in your question.

```
var max=50;
$('.blog article').each( function (){
    if($(this).height()>max)
        $(this).closest('h4').hide();
});
```